# How to Create ER Diagram in Crow's foot notation from MySQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship, erd

I am trying to create ER diagrams for Bank Management system. I was able to create ER Diagram from MySQL Workbench using the MySQL code I wrote for the Model. but, MySQL workbench only producing ER Diagrams in a UML notation, but I want the Diagrams in Crow's Foot Notation. is there any tool that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the notation in Workbench: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-data-modeling-menus.html#wb-relationship-notation-menu